# Identify older breaker type. Pictures

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

Older house built in florida in 1950's. 
states it was "rewired" at some point.

Looking to add a breaker. and do some shopping

Wondering if someone can ID these breakers so i know what im looking for.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image: breaker box]

Comment: Can you post a photo showing the rest of the breakers in the panel? You have at least one alien visible, so I suspect there may be more in there...

Comment: ill try and remmemeber tonight.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I'm not sure how to check with one that old, but I wonder if the challenger breaker was ever classified for use with this panel -- they're BR compatible, and the panel is BR compatible, so physically and electrically it should be possible.  Whether they ever bothered to get the UL classification I don't know.

Comment: @NateStrickland -- probably not -- there's no classification mark on the breaker that I can see

Answer (score 1):

One of the types of breakers mentioned in the panel label, Bryant GFCB, are still made.  Bryant was bought by Eaton some time back, so they are now known as Eaton BR   GFCI series.  Most big box and stores stock them, or any electrical supply house will be able to get them for you.

[image: Eaton Type BR GFCI Circuit Breaker]

Image from [Home Depot - Eaton Type BR GFCB](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-Type-BR-15-Amp-Single-Pole-Ground-Fault-Circuit-Breaker-GFCB115CS/100212125)

Interestingly, as Harper notes in the comments, regular non-GFCI type BR breakers are not listed for use with this panel for some reason.  I expect they would still be safe to use since the busing is identical on regular and GCFI type BR breakers, but it would not pass an inspection that way since it is not listed for that use.  So the only currently manufactured breakers originally listed for use with this panel are going to be GFCI type.

It appears that Eaton also makes some cross-listed breakers that are compatible with the original Crouse-Hinds ones.  See [this PDF](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eaton.com%2Fecm%2Fidcplg%3FIdcService%3DGET_FILE%26allowInterrupt%3D1%26RevisionSelectionMethod%3DLatestReleased%26Rendition%3DPrimary%26%26dDocName%3DSA00304001E&ei=sTRRU--kGLe1sATK9YDoBg&usg=AFQjCNFZUbprHAGwzCTW6lvYbkU4FLvqKQ&bvm=bv.65058239,d.cWc&cad=rja) for more details

Comment: Eaton GFCBs are a particular sub-group of BR.  As you might guess from the initials, "Ground Fault Circuit Breaker".  The panel is not listed for BR generally.

Comment: @Harper, good catch.  I updated the answer.

Comment: I was just looking to put in a 40 amp single pole simple breaker to power the new metal shed building out back. . im looking at a BR140 or BR150 type breaker. these should fit right?

Comment: 50A single pole is going to be hard to find, because at that current level usually you want double pole for 240V.  Are you sure you want 120V only in your shed?  If you're putting in a subpanel, half your breaker spaces will be dead that way.

Comment: If you want a double-pole, this one would do the trick: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-BR-50-Amp-2-Pole-Self-Test-Ground-Fault-Circuit-Breaker-GFTCB250CS/206676933

Comment: If you want single pole, or don't want your entire shed on a GFCI (which honestly isn't a bad idea to have), then you're better off going with Murray breakers as @ThreePhaseEel recommends.  This one would work for single pole: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Murray-50-Amp-Single-Pole-Type-MP-Circuit-Breaker-MP150/206632049

Comment: Or the double pole Murray: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Siemens-50-Amp-Double-Pole-Type-MP-Circuit-Breaker-MP250/202253150

Comment: wanting to stay single pole. the box is crowded.  My sub panel in the metal building has GFI's . Not too worried about the power going out there.

Comment: If it's jsut panel space you're worried about, there are Murray quad breakers that would work in this situation.  For example, this breaker could replace your exising double pole 40A breaker in the picture, and provide an additional double pole 40A using no additional space: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Murray-2-40-Amp-Double-Pole-Type-MP-T-Quadplex-Plug-In-Circuit-Breaker-MP240240CT2/206632080

Answer (score 1):

You can't just put any old breaker in any panel. Some may seem to "snap in", but the shape of the busbars is different enough to cause poor contact, heating and arcing.   This is why a **UL Listing** is very important (and required by NEC 110.2).

However, some manufacturers build breakers for competitor panels.  They go to UL and have their breakers **UL Classified** for the competitor panels they fit.

Cutler Hammer (now Eaton) [did exactly that](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/catalog/electrical-circuit-protection/classified-circuit-breakers.technical.html), with **CL**, a "CLassified" breaker line that is designed to replace certain Crouse-Hinds breakers as well as several other kinds.

The Crouse-Hinds MP series (for example MP120) is listed on the label for this panel, and the Eaton CL series (for example CL120) is classified to replace it. *Note this is not the same as the Eaton BR (BRyant) series*.

Answer (score 1):

### This is really a Murray panel

The Murray product line changed hands several times (from Murray, through Arrow-Hart and Crouse-Hinds branding, then finally to its current home as part of Siemens as the rest of Arrow-Hart/Crouse-Hinds was picked up by Eaton/Cooper).  However, the design of the MP breaker-busbar connection has changed little over the years, so modern Murray/Siemens MP breakers should still be workable in your panel, and are readily available as well (including all the fancy types).

### Other options

If the Murray MP breakers are not available where you are at, you do have other options.  First, you can use breakers that have been UL *classified* for use with other panels; this designation applies to the Eaton CL series, but comes with some restrictions on what is available (nothing >50A, and only a limited selection of exotics, although a basic AFCI and GFCI selection is available in CL).

Your panel, like many pre-Siemens Murray/Crouse-Hinds/Arrow-Hart panels, also has a *limited* listing for some other Eaton/Bryant/Westinghouse breakers; in particular, it is listed for BR GFCI (GFCB) breakers, albeit *not* any of the other BR breaker types, and a few Westinghouse (now Eaton) HQP types, which also includes the Eaton QPGFT GFCI breakers.  However, the last listing is rather unhelpful, because it's limited to 15A and 20A branch breakers only, and not any of the larger sizes; neither of these help you with AFCI requirements, either, for which the only options are MP or CL.